# Swift Migration - Parse Cloud Function Wont Trigger

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, parse-server

I am a beginner Swift Developer doing the Swift migration of an iOS app that is using Parse. 
The production app is using Swift 2 and working properly. 
I updated my code to Swift 3 so the app is launching now but my Parse Cloud Function doesn't trigger and I can't find why.

Here is the code

```
@IBAction func action_signup_v2(_ sender: UIButton) {
    Mixpanel.sharedInstance().track("ios_signup_phone_number_sent")
    sender.isEnabled = false
    let phoneNumberKit = PhoneNumberKit()

    print("Tapped send button")
    let phone_number=text_field_signup.text
    do {
        let phoneNumber = try phoneNumberKit.parse(phone_number!, withRegion: "US")
        let phoneE164: String = phoneNumberKit.format(phoneNumber, toType: .e164)
        let phone_clean = String(phoneE164.characters.dropFirst(2)) as String
        self.phoneNumber=phone_clean

        print(phone_number as Any)
        PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "send_code", withParameters: ["phoneNumber":phone_clean,"language":"en"]) {
            (response: Any?, error: Error?) in
            print("Parse function triggered")
            if error == nil {
                // If there is no error
                print("no err")
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "go_to_verify_controller", sender: self)
            } else {
                Mixpanel.sharedInstance().track("ios_error_signup_phone_number")
                self.present_alert(title: "Oops", content: "Our servers are too busy please try again in a few moment.")
                print(error ?? "There is an error");
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("Generic parser error")
        self.present_alert(title: "Oops", content: "Please check the format of your phone number and try again.")
        Mixpanel.sharedInstance().track("ios_error_signup_phone_number", properties : ["error_message":"generic parser error"])
    }
}
```

Here is what's printed:

`Tapped send button
Optional("(650) 460-3317")`

Here is more information about Parse

The `PFCloud` class provides methods for interacting with Parse Cloud Functions.
 */
open class PFCloud : NSObject {

```
/**
 Calls the given cloud function *asynchronously* with the parameters provided.

 @param function The function name to call.
 @param parameters The parameters to send to the function.

 @return The task, that encapsulates the work being done.
 */
open class func callFunction(inBackground function: String, withParameters parameters: [AnyHashable : Any]?) -> BFTask<AnyObject>


/**
 Calls the given cloud function *asynchronously* with the parameters provided
 and executes the given block when it is done.

 @param function The function name to call.
 @param parameters The parameters to send to the function.
 @param block The block to execute when the function call finished.
 It should have the following argument signature: `^(id result, NSError *error)`.
 */
open class func callFunction(inBackground function: String, withParameters parameters: [AnyHashable : Any]?, block: Parse.PFIdResultBlock? = nil)
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try changing that function to run with block like this:

(The block to execute when the function call finished):

```
PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "send_code", withParameters:["phoneNumber":phone_clean,"language":"en"] , block: { (response: Any?, error: Error?) in

if error == nil {
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It doesnt do anything more. "parse function triggered" is not printed.

Comment: Can you paste the define too please. the cloud function so that i can see

Comment: I have updated my question. What do you mean by "the define"? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It wont, becasue it not within the error. Please post the function in your Main.js file so that i can see the success or promises. That is what i'am referring too. Also print the logs ( VERBOSE = 1) and post it here.

Comment: Out of interest, did this stop working after you moved to parse-server ? or just the upgrade to swift 3 ?

Comment: Also in your cloud code Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); is deprecated with parse-server.

Comment: also if you can remove that link, it has alot of sensitive information in it!

Comment: i dont see how that function can work. your problem lies with that file. You need to make use of  useMasterKey: true in that query on the Users.

Comment: The app is still running with Swift 2.2, it stopped working after moving to swift 3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135202/discussion-between-cliffordwh-and-quentin-del).

Answer (score 1):

Hello Everyone function is not triggered because Parse is ShutDown. :-)

https://parseplatform.github.io
The Parse service is now shut down. To all the developers out there, it was a pleasure helping you build apps. Goodbye and good luck! If you have any concerns regarding the migration, refer to the migration guide or reach out to migration@parse.com.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, in the Swift Migration, I forgot to add the "_" in the

`func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {`